# Any good tools to migrate from MySQL to SQLite3?

Tags: mysql, migration, sqlite

I'm struggling to find a good tool to help me migrate a MySQL database to SQLite.  I've seen a couple of different Perl scripts (including one discovered here), but they do not appear to work correctly for me.

Comment: You might want to reference the tools you've tried any why they didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 6):

see all converters here http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools
it has mysql converter

Comment: Thanks for such a good reference. You saved my day! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Data Transfer tool of Valentina Studio 5.1   to copy records of tables, from any to any of supported databases: SQLite, mySQL, postgreSQL, Valentina DB.

Answer (score -1):

I use data loader for migrating almost any data, it helps me to convert MSSQL to MYSQL, MS access to MSSQL, mysql, csv loader, foxpro and MSSQL to MS access, MYSQl, CSV, foxpro etc. In my view this is a best Data Migration Tool

Download Free : http://www.dbload.com

Comment: The poster was asking specifically for conversion from MySQL to SQLite. However, this particular tool does not support SQLite